# What's the correct use of apostrophe here?

Tags: apostrophe

There are two men named Bill Bass. I want to write the following two sentences. I want the two sentences below to refer to both of them, as plural, not possessive. Is this correct?

> I think this should be the Bill Bass' Memorial Picnic. That way it can be a memorial to both Bill Bass'

Comment: What do you need the apostrophe in the second instance for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hard and fast rule may be possible to state, but generally, a name ending in *s* takes *-es* for the plural and where required, the apostrophe comes thereafter.

cf. "the Jone**ses**"

> I think this should be the Bill Bass**es'** Memorial Picnic. That way it can be a memorial to both Bill Bass**es**.

Comment: The Double Bass Memorial Picnic?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The Double Bass is alive and kicking, or rather, playing well, no memorial anytime soon.